# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8090/plotting-stereonets-in-r) asks "Is there a package for R to plot Schmidt nets, like it is done in geology?"; [the first answer posted](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/8092/94) said "Try the [RockFab](https://libraries.io/cran/RockFab) library on CRAN", which at least at first glance seems to me to answer the question. It's not entirely clear whether the asker wants a stereographic or Lambert equal-area projection, but at least for the first case RockFab seems to do the job. So it might not be the right answer, and it could certainly be more detailed, but it's an entirely possible answer given that the question hasn't yet been clarified. In fact, someone else posted the same answer after this one was deleted.

Since the answer gathered a quorum of close votes on grounds of "does not answer the question", I assume there's something I'm missing here. Why does it not answer the question?

Comment: I agree that it should not have been deleted.

Comment: Although it answer completely answered the question (Is there an R package ...?->  Yes, there is. Use RockFab), I would expect a brief code example on how to actually plot a Schmidt net with RockFab. The 'answer' "Try Package XY" is a comment from my point of view. However, it would be fair to give the answering user the opportunity to improve his answer.

Comment: To the topic of the original question: According to [this appendix](https://www.geophysik.uni-muenchen.de/~malservisi/GlobaleGeophysik/stereonet_text.pdf) (p.695), the Schmidt net is an equal-area projection. Hence the function `StereoWeb` in the `RockFab` package might be appropriate. Although, if there was no function in RockFab being able to plot a Schmidt net, the answer was be definately wrong ... .

Comment: @daniel.neumann As I understand it, a Schmidt net is actually a type of graph paper used to plot Lambert azimuthal equal-area projections by hand. But I suspect that the questioner doesn't *actually* want a program that draws a Schmidt net, but a program that produces an equal-are projection of data. Or possibly a program that produces a stereographic projection of data, as the title implies. On reflection, the question is so confused that maybe it should be closed until the asker edits it to be more specific.

Comment: @Pont I completely agree with your last point.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close because it seemed to fit a comment, not an answer. Note that there is an answer now that basically says the same thing, but is slightly longer. I'd close that too. One liners shouldn't be an answer..

Answer (score 0):

A good answer tells not only "what" but "why." As such, a one-liner does not make a good answer.

"Try XYZ resource" is a good *start*. A good answer will finish the job by explaining why XYZ resource fits the question well, or at least better than other resources out there.

Answers that are incomplete are sooner or later deleted to make room for (and encourage) better answers.